# Issues with Personal Contribution Pages / Events / Joomla

Tags: joomla, personal-campaign-pages

I have PCP turned on - the person is able to set one up - 
When someone goes to donate they get the error below - I also get the error even when I am logged in as an admin - so I don't think this is a permission issue with the ACL -

Joomla 3.8.5 Civi 4.7.27

Example page http://bit.ly/lzzebra

CiviCRM-001 -   @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css); @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/crm-i.css); @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);    Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred. The page you requested is currently unavailable.

[Return to home page.](https://norcalcarcinet.org/)

function toggle( element ) { var parent = element.parentNode; var className = parent.className; if ( className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } else { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } }

Comment: For what it is worth - if I set up a personal campaign page as part of a contribution page - it work perfectly

Comment: can you check CiviCRM logs for detailed error?

Answer (score 2):

So thanks to Brian at ICD who helped troubleshoot this - somehow the PCP that was set up for the event was done in a way that while it was a contribution page - it was pointing to the event ID -
This required some updating of the event PCP to point to the correct contribution page instead of the event. I am not sure how it happened - but it is fixed - I check on new event to see if I can select the appropriate contribution page and I can -